# Is there an algorithm that would allow two way string to GUID encoding

Tags: encoding, guid

I need to be able to encode string values into unique GUID representation so that when a GUID is passed back to the algorithm, it could decode it into an original string.

So, for instance, it would be able to take a string, 'API Users' and return a GUID, for instance: b0363782-5207-420e-9188-6bff7369593

Then when passed 'b0363782-5207-420e-9188-6bff7369593' it would return 'API Users' back.

Is creation of such mapping algorithm possible in theory?

Of course, I can persist the mapping in the storage and then relate back the string to an issued GUID, but I am looking for an encoding-based way of doing it so that the resulting GUID would store the string.

Comment: What is the length limit and character set of the string? As that increases, the ability to encode the permutations of the string rapidly exceed the permutations of a guid.

Comment: if you would need it just in the other direction: string -> UUID then UUID version 5 could be a perfect fit.